# Combining a BackoffSupervisor with a Router

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Can I combine a [BackoffSupervisor](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.11/general/supervision.html#Delayed_restarts_with_the_BackoffSupervisor_pattern) with a [Router](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/routing.html#Pool)?

The concepts seem very similar, but it seems as though a BackoffSupervisor isn't itself a SupervisionStrategy I can give to the Router.

I can wrap the Props used by a Router in a BackoffSupervisor, so each child in the Router is actually the pair of supervisor/actor. But, this breaks the SmallestMailboxPool, probably among others, because the intermediate supervisor actor's mailbox is always empty. (it just forwards to the actor it supervises)

The goal being, of course, a Router that restarts the children with a backoff.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't really possible implementing back off supervision as a supervision strategy as those needs to decide directly how to deal with failure. This means that if you want to combine that with routing where the routing strategy uses some information about the recipient mailbox you will have to implement your own router taking care of these two concerns.

Note though that the routers that does not inspect mailboxes will work fine routing to `BackoffSupervisor`-protected actors. (So, no problem if you use `RoundRobin`, `Random`, `Broadcast`, `ScatterGatherFirstCompleted`, `TailChoppingPool` or `ConsistentHashing`).

Comment: That's what I did, used RoundRobinPool. I don't like it though, because messages to a BackoffSupervisor that's waiting for the backoff delay appear to get dropped in deadletters. If I have a pool of actors, some of the other members may be healthy, and blind round-robin means dropping things unnecessarily.